# others accessing setApprovalForAll ERC721

Tags: solidity, erc-721

While I was skimming through open zeppelin's `ERC721BasicToken.sol` I came across a problem.

When setting the approval of a given operator

```
  function setApprovalForAll(address _to, bool _approved) public {
    require(_to != msg.sender);
    operatorApprovals[msg.sender][_to] = _approved;
    emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender, _to, _approved);
  }
```

I've noticed that the visibility of the function is `public`. Doesn't it mean that anyone can modify an operator which was previously set before?

For example, I would create a contract that can control over a deployed ERC721Token contract.

```
contract TokenAccessor { 
  ERC721Token public nft;

  constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
    nft= ERC721Token(_tokenAddress);
  }
}
```

And from the migrations script, I would pass in the address of someone's deployed ERC721 token contract.

```
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TokenAccessor, "0x......")
    .then(() => {
```

This way, I think anyone can access `setApprovalForAll` to change the operator?

```
contract TokenAccessor { 
  ERC721Token public nft;

  constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
    nft= ERC721Token(_tokenAddress);
  }

   function changeOperator() public {
    nft.setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've noticed that the visibility of the function is public. Doesn't it mean that anyone can modify an operator which was previously set before?

The `public` visibility just means that the function can be called from outside of the contract, ie, by another contract or from a wallet.

The function you mentioned, `setApprovalForAll`, is used to give another address permission to transfer all of *your* tokens. If it weren't `public` (or `external`) then nobody could use this function.

But the `_to` address specifies the address to which you want to grant permission, it doesn't specify the address that owns the tokens. The latter is inferred inside the function using `msg.sender`.

So no, you can't use this function to arbitrarily assign permissions, because you can't arbitrarily change `msg.sender`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that I shouldn't have passed `msg.sender`. But you can still pass in the address of a `TokenAccessor` contract to `_to` address which works right?

Comment: Yes, in the `setApprovalForAll` function you provided, you can pass any address as `_to` as long as it's not the same as `msg.sender`. That includes a contract address.

Comment: Ok, so I can change my `changeOperator()` to take address type `changeOperator(address _contract)` and pass the value to `nft.setApprovalForAll(_contract, true);` which means `TokenAccessor` contract is now the operator. If this is true, anyone can still change the existing operator right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, or what you're trying to achieve. But it's worth noting that `msg.sender` is _not_ preserved if a contract executes a function on another contract. So when your `TokenAccessor` calls `nft.setApprovalForAll`, the NFT contract will have TokenAccessor's address as `msg.sender`.

Comment: That makes sense. All clear now thanks.

Comment: Hi @AnAllergyToAnalogy I am using the setApprovalForAll function on a Marketplace I have created, whereby the owners of NFTs grant my Smart Contract approval to sell their Tokens on their behalf. I have noticed however, that once this approval has been granted, any user can call the safeTransferFrom function without going through the Marketplace. I have described the scenario in more details at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114135/safetransferfrom-being-called-by-anyone Am I missing something here? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry @AnAllergyToAnalogy I have also noticed that actually anyone can call the safeTransferFrom function once setApprovalForAll has been called, including the purchaser, as explained at the link provided above. Isn't this a glitch in the OpenZeppelin Conracts?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to remember that:

```
require(_to != msg.sender);
operatorApprovals[msg.sender][_to] = _approved;
```

Basically prevents you from adding random addresses to be given permissions over other peoples tokens.

`operatorApprovals[msg.sender][_to]` means that you can only approve the token permissions, over tokens which YOU own. You can't just call the contract for other tokens owned by other addresses.